# How to check if a particular date exists?

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nscalendar

how can I check if a particular date exists?. For example, if I do the following:

```
 NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setYear:2011];
[dateComponents setMonth:2];
[dateComponents setDay:29];

NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
[dateComponents release];

NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

I will just get March 1st. I cannot find a function that allows this, the only way I can do it, is by checking after creating the NSDate if the components agree with what I ordered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]` method:

```
+ (BOOL)dateExistsYear:(int)year month:(int)month day:(int)day
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd";

    NSString* inputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4d%2d%2d",
                        year,month,day];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inputString];

    return nil != date;
}
```

If you give a valid date, then `dateFromString:` will succeed, otherwise, it will return `nil`.

Comment: That works. Though use `"%04d%02d%02d"` to zero-pad the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
+(BOOL)dateExistsYear:(int)year month:(int)month day:(int)day{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [components setYear:year];
    [components setMonth:month];
    [components setDay:day];

    NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

    [components release];
    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    if([components year] != year || [components month] != month || [components day] != day){
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I've checked existence of all days from January 1st, 2000 to December 12, 2012.

```
2011-04-28 11:42:57.130 Test[1543:903] interval 1.103822 // using the above function  
2011-04-28 11:42:59.498 Test[1543:903] interval 2.367271 // using dateformatter
```

It is still faster just to check the components.

Comment: The upper limit for your test should really be [21 Dec 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/December_21,_2012). ;)